# Slow Boot Times -- "gave up waiting for root device" error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu this past Sunday. This afternoon after my laptop battery was drained, I plugged it in and started to boot into Ubuntu (I have a dual-boot setup along with Windows 8.1). I was faced with a black screen for a long time (one of the things that made using Ubuntu exciting was that it was relatively boot into) until the error in the title of this thread came up.

I have been googling around for the entire day trying to fix this and I have found a a few temporary solutions:
1- Change in my BIOS, SATA settings to IDE (takes forever to boot)
2- Adding a rootdelay=40 or more to grub (/etc/default/grub) (takes maybe slightly less time than 1)
3- entering 'exit' as a command after getting the "gave up waiting for root device" message.

All these solutions make booting into Ubuntu really slow and I'd like the speed I got yesterday and Sunday (when I first installed Ubuntu).

Things I did today before problem started occuring:
1.Booted into Windows and shrunk one of my Windows partition with the intent of allocating more to /home partition
2.Installed indicator-cpufreq

Things I have done after problem occured:
1.Used GParted on LiveUSB to delete all three partitions of installed Ubuntu (/,/home and swap)
2.Reinstalled Ubuntu with more allocated space to all three partitions

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can have this problem when the entry in /etc/fstab no longer matches the disk.

You may have something like this

`UUID=d77c6fe4-f734-4b17-a614-22a96e6b8e28 /  ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1`

On a laptop you might want to replace this with

`/dev/sda3 /  ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1`

(or whatever your root partition is)

Comment: Hi, changing the UUIDs as you suggested (using my correct partitions, of course) lead to a load screen that says " The disk drive for /media/sda1 is not ready yet or not present."

Comment: I made the mistake of doing UUID=/dev/sda3 ...... I have ammended it now. However, the problem is still there.

Comment: Also, on the "gave up waiting for root device” error screen. One of the later error messages is "ALERT!UUID=(Don't know for sure but I recognize the ID as my root partion) Does not exist